# Can a kite take advantage of crosswinds to gain speed?

Tags: aerodynamics, crosswind, experimental-aircraft, ultralight, sailplane

In a form off a kite can wind be redirected like a sail boat in any direction? Can cross winds around a jet stream be helpful in speed in such a design?

Comment: You can't sail a sailboat directly up wind. Winds don't usually oppose, so what do you mean by crosswind?

Comment: related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24420/can-a-foot-ball-field-size-kite-carrying-person-s-fly-around-the-world-by-ridi

Comment: Boats have a keel and contact with water.

Comment: Hi Jen, I modified the title of your question.  Aviation.SE is a little bit different than most web sites.  Around here, we encourage you to repeat your actual question in the question title.  If I misunderstood what you were asking, please feel free to re-edit.

Comment: @RonBeyer: It depends on the type of sail you use :D

Comment: @slebetman Do you have any references for that? I can't find any kind of sail that can go directly upwind without tacking.

Comment: @RonBeyer: A windmill sail can go upwind. Though not sails in the traditional sense because the windmill is used to drive a propeller it is technically sailing. It's not so much the propeller that's pushing the ship - it's the interaction between the windmill and the propeller that extracts energy out of the shear forces between the wind and the water - the same way a normal cloth sail work with the keel.

Comment: Plane can. Look dynamic soaring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need a kite? A glider is much better suited to the task.

Again, nature has invented this long ago. Albatrosses use a technique called [dynamic soaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_soaring) to cover wide distances over water, using the windshear close to the surface.

[Humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingo_Renner) have tried to imitate this with gliders, albeit with limited success. The few who tried it could indeed stay in the air by harvesting energy from windshear, but the dynamic loads (up to 4 g) were too much to do this over an extended time.

Comment: a plane cannot bend its wings to maximize redirection of like a sail boat.

Comment: @Jen: Redirection of what? If you have discovered a new law of physics, we would like to hear about it!

Comment: a bird can bend one wing in on direction to redirect wind downward from a cross wind some what like a sail gliders can do that but a kite can.